# How to solve error "java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm running the following code:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java", "root", "");
        System.out.println("connection established");
        String select_all = "select*from prac1";
        Statement ob = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet ob2 = ob.executeQuery(select_all);
        System.out.println(ob2.getString(1) + " " + ob2.getString(2) + " " + ob2.getString(3));
    }
}
```

This gives me in the console:

```
connection established

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:517)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:870)
        at App.main(App.java:11)
```

I am just getting started with this, so there might be a dumb thing that I must have done and not see it, so I apologise in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java", "root", "root");
    System.out.println("connection established");
    String select_all = "select*from xyz where name = 'aa'";
    Statement ob = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet ob2 = ob.executeQuery(select_all);
    ob2.next();
    System.out.println(ob2.getString(1) + " " + ob2.getString(2) + " " + ob2.getString(3));

}
```

Description:
Resultset maintains a cursor which always points before the first row, so here in this case it was not pointing to a specific row, so we used "ob2.next()" to move the cursor to get the result;
But still it will give the result for only one row. But if you want all the records from that table you can write like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java", "root", "root");
    System.out.println("connection established");
    String select_all = "select*from xyz where name = 'aa'";
    Statement ob = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet ob2 = ob.executeQuery(select_all);
    while(ob2.next()) {
        System.out.println(ob2.getString(1) + " " + ob2.getString(2) + " " + ob2.getString(3));
    }

}
```

The return type of "next()" method is boolean so it returns true if there is any next row and then moves the cursor to the next position.
So now in this while loop ob2.next() moves the cursor and you get the values of first row, then after first iteration the cursor is at before second row position and so on till there is any row left. once row finished "next()" returns false and breaks the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `ResultSet` as a set of rooms that have a door and every time you get in a room you can get data from this room.
Think of the rooms as rows of data. When you first get a `ResultSet` by using `executeQuery(..)` you stand outside of all the rooms, and just in front of the door from the first room, you have to get in to retrieve data. You cannot just say `rs.getString(..)`. How do you get in and traverse the rooms/rows?

By using `resutSet.next()`.
So before starting to get data, execute this function to "go in the room".

It is very often used in a while loop:

```java
while(rs.next())
{
   ...
}
```